# surjective group Homomorphism from $A_5$ to $A _4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Is there a  surjective group  homomorphism from  $f :\mathbb{A_5} \rightarrow \mathbb{A _4} ?$

My attempt : i know that there is  no  surjective group  homomorphism from  $f :\mathbb{S_5} \rightarrow \mathbb{S _4} $ because $A_5$ is the  only  normal subgroup  after $n \ge 5$.

Here im confused  about   $A_5$ and $A_4$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, such morphism would have a  nontrivial kernel but $A_5$ is simple.

Comment: thanks  u @K76u4vkweek547v7,,,,,,ur  name  is long   dificult to type